# Flutter DatePicker without day. Using Future<DateTime?> showDatePicker. PLUGIN RESTRICTED

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Is it possible have a YEAR-MONTH picker with only the month and the year with the current showDatePicker without using third-party PLUGINS!!

Note: As a result the day selection layout should not be visible.

Comment: For someone facing this problem, maybe this solucion helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154812/8377018

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The stock pickers do not allow to have month and year only.

You could use the [month_picker_dialog](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/month_picker_dialog) package available in the pub page by Dimitri Krivoj.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, this is almost perfect to me, just not have PT-BR support. But is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Its clashing with firebase_auth: ^0.20.1 (because flutter_app depends on both firebase_auth ^0.20.1 and month_picker_dialog any, version solving failed)

Comment: Is it possible to change the blue color of this widget?

Comment: @AashwiinRoghan yes, by changing the primarySwatch in the theme of the application.

Comment: For those are facing issues with UI out of bounds, I suggest switch to month_picker_dialog package

Answer (score 8):

Use [flutter_datetime_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker) with custom model which disables the last column

```dart
class CustomMonthPicker extends DatePickerModel {
  CustomMonthPicker({DateTime currentTime, DateTime minTime, DateTime maxTime,
    LocaleType locale}) : super(locale: locale, minTime: minTime, maxTime:
  maxTime, currentTime: currentTime);

  @override
  List<int> layoutProportions() {
    return [1, 1, 0];
  }
}
```

and show the picker with custom model

```dart
DatePicker.showPicker(context,
  ...
  pickerModel: CustomMonthPicker(
    minTime: DateTime(2020, 1, 1),
    maxTime: DateTime.now(),
    currentTime: DateTime.now()
  )
  ...
)
```

[image]

Comment: The plugin is outdated. You can use this maintained version https://pub.dev/packages/month_picker_dialog_2

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `YearPicker` widget to show only a yearly calendar.
A typical example is:

```dart
TextFormField(
  validator: value.isEmpty ? 'this field is required' : null,
  readOnly: true,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0),
    hintText: 'Pick Year',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
  ),
  onTap: () => handleReadOnlyInputClick(context),
)

void handleReadOnlyInputClick(context) {
  showBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: YearPicker(
          selectedDate: DateTime(1997),
          firstDate: DateTime(1995),
          lastDate: DateTime.now(),
          onChanged: (val) {
            print(val);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
    )
  );
}
```

**Note: you don't have to use a `bottomSheet`, you can nest it anywhere a widget is valid.**

Answer (score 3):

For someone else that needs a different approach, setting the dateFormat to 'yyyy-mm' would hide the day field.

```
DatePicker.showDatePicker(
  ...
  dateFormat:'yyyy-mm',
  ...
);
```

you can find this widget from this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker)

Comment: What package did you use for `DatePicker.showDatePicker()`?

Comment: I used 'package:flutter_cupertino_date_picker/flutter_cupertino_date_picker.dart'

Comment: this is unlisted

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to remove "day" from the official DatePicker widget. You should create a copy of the DatePicker Widget and remove the "day" part. Then use your own class in your project instead of the "original" one.