# How can i hide day from cupertino date picker

Tags: dart, flutter

i need to pic only year and month from the date picker, so how can i hide day from date picker.

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
    initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
        print(newdate);
        widget.card.expDateTime = newdate.toString();
         dateCnt.text = newdate.toString().split(" ")[0];
    },
    minimumYear: DateTime.now().year,
    minimumDate: DateTime.now(),
    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
)
```

Comment: Do you want a datepicker UI without day? Or just want to ignore day after picking up a date?

Comment: i need to hide day from datepicker.

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem, tried the package [flutter_cupertino_date_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker#-readme-tab-) but it looks like it don't have the hability to format only month and year excluding day, so you need to program on it to extend the capabilities.  To me seemed more logical to change the build in CupertinoDatePicker that comes with Flutter, what I did was copy all the content of '/Users/your_user_name/developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/date_picker.dart' in another file in my local envirronment, I called `cupertino_picker_extended.dart`, then (because I wanted a quick way) on line 1182 I changed: `Text(localizations.datePickerDayOfMonth(day),...` for `Text('',...`

Then where you need to use the customed Picker call it like:

```
import 'package:local_app/ui/widgets/cupertino_picker_extended.dart' as CupertinoExtended;
```

and use it:

```
  CupertinoExtended.CupertinoDatePicker(
    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime value) {
      setDate('${value.month}/${value.year}', setDateFunction,
          section, arrayPos);
    },
    initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
    mode: CupertinoExtended.CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
  ),
```

This is the result:
[image: screenshot]

Hope it help someone and save the time I been looking for a easy and quick solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to look at [flutter_cupertino_date_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker#-readme-tab-) package this to do so. you can avoid picking date from user.

like below example i edited as you wish. i hope that it help you to achieve what you want.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_cupertino_date_picker/flutter_cupertino_date_picker.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Date Picker Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      );
    }
  }

  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
  }

  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    String _datetime = '';
    int _year = 2018;
    int _month = 11;

    String _lang = 'en';
    String _format = 'yyyy-mm';
    bool _showTitleActions = true;

    TextEditingController _langCtrl = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController _formatCtrl = TextEditingController();

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _langCtrl.text = 'zh';
      _formatCtrl.text = 'yyyy-mm';

      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      _year = now.year;
      _month = now.month;
    }

    /// Display date picker.
    void _showDatePicker() {
      final bool showTitleActions = false;
      DatePicker.showDatePicker(
        context,
        showTitleActions: _showTitleActions,
        minYear: 1970,
        maxYear: 2020,
        initialYear: _year,
        initialMonth: _month,
        confirm: Text(
          'custom ok',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        cancel: Text(
          'custom cancel',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan),
        ),
        locale: _lang,
        dateFormat: _format,
        onChanged: (year, month,date) {
          debugPrint('onChanged date: $year-$month');

          if (!showTitleActions) {
            _changeDatetime(year, month);
          }
        },
        onConfirm: (year, month,date) {
          _changeDatetime(year, month);
        },
      );
    }

    void _changeDatetime(int year, int month) {
      setState(() {
        _year = year;
        _month = month;
        _datetime = '$year-$month';
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Date Picker Demo'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // show title actions checkbox
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Show title actions',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                  Checkbox(
                    value: _showTitleActions,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _showTitleActions = value;
                      });
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),

              // Language input field
              TextField(
                controller: _langCtrl,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Language',
                  hintText: 'en',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _lang = value;
                },
              ),

              // Formatter input field
              TextField(
                controller: _formatCtrl,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Formatter',
                  hintText: 'yyyy-mm-dd / yyyy-mmm-dd / yyyy-mmmm-dd',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _format = value;
                },
              ),

              // Selected date
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Selected Date:',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '$_datetime',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _showDatePicker,
          tooltip: 'Show DatePicker',
          child: Icon(Icons.date_range),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There has been updates on the [flutter_cupertino_date_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker#-readme-tab) package. You can now specify a date format

```
 DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
            maxDateTime: DateTime.now(),
              dateFormat:'MMMM-yyyy'
            );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way to do this is to just add

```
mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.monthYear
```

and whole code will be

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
       mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.monthYear,
       initialDateTime: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 2)),
       onDateTimeChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _expireDateController.text = DateFormat('MM/yy').format(value);
          });
       },
       minimumDate: DateTime.now(),
 ),
```

Answer (score -3):

> This is the way to go

```
  Widget datetime() {
return CupertinoDatePicker(
  initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
  onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
    print(newdate);
  },
  minimumYear: 2010,
  maximumYear: 2030,
  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
);
```

}